# How do I execute multiple arguments in console using argparse?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I've been reading for a few hours and I'm beginning to give up so I'm here for the punishment. I am trying to run a python file which requires arguments. Help says

Usage: Eventbot.py [-h] [-id ID] [-num NUM] [--wait WAIT] url

I try typing python eventbot.py 1 1 https://www.eventbrite.com/e/cooking-at-home-with-yao-zhao-all-about-sichuan-pepper-tickets-137805759737

But it says invalid argument 1 https://www.eventbrite.com/e/cooking-at-home-with-yao-zhao-all-about-sichuan-pepper-tickets-137805759737

I've tried adding the --wait 1 at the end but that doesn't work.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
try:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Eventbrite bot to automate securing event tickets")
    parser.add_argument("url",    type=str, help="Eventbrite event URL")
    parser.add_argument("-id",    type=str, help="Ticket ID to purchase")
    parser.add_argument("-num",   type=str, help="Number of tickets to purchase")
    parser.add_argument("--wait", type=int, help="Seconds the browser should wait for DOM to load")
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Assuming the two 1s are the ID and NUM, and lets say the URL was supposed to be `google.com`, try running `python eventbot.py -id 1 -num 1 google.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `-id` and `-num` arguments are preceded by a `-`, that means that they are not positional arguments, like the `url` argument is. Since these arguments aren't positional, they act exactly like your `--wait` argument, which also is not positional. In order to pass a value to the argument, specify the desired value after the argument name, for example,

```
python eventbot.py -id 1 -num 1 https://www.eventbrite.com/e/cooking-at-home-with-yao-zhao-all-about-sichuan-pepper-tickets-137805759737
```